# `bitcoin-core/secp256k1` vs `bitcoin/src/secp256k1` - what to use?

Tags: bitcoin

There are two secp256k1 implementations that are related to Bitcoin-Core:

- [bitcoin-core/secp256k1](https://github.com/bitcoin-core/secp256k1)
- [bitcoin/src/secp256k1](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/tree/master/src/secp256k1)

What is the more authoritative implementation?
What secp256k1 library should be used?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm concerned, that's the same thing. The most recent version is here bitcoin-core/secp256k1 and from time to time is pulled by developers in bitcoin/src/secp256k1